# How to add previous/next options using angularjs or javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

How can I add `previous/next` **buttons/options/links** in my example so that I can move forward and backward steps after clicking on those options as per requirement in my third tab for the given content using **angularjs** or **javascript** or **jquery**. I have created [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/6qm7jeo3/1/)

Comment: Where do you want to add previous/next button and where it will redirect you

Comment: in my third tab, it is having couple of buttons(Test, Test1, etc). If we add previous/next options so that we can go forward and backward to display it's content in the same tab.

Comment: Editted fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mavdhana/6qm7jeo3/3/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you looking for such behavior:

http://jsfiddle.net/6qm7jeo3/5/

I have added a `prev` and `next` function. Please have a look at it.

```
angular.module('TabsApp', [])
  .controller('TabsCtrl', ['$scope', '$location', function($scope, $location) {
    $scope.tabs = [{
      title: 'One',
      url: 'one.tpl.html'
    }, {
      title: 'Two',
      url: 'two.tpl.html'
    }, {
      title: 'Three',
      url: 'three.tpl.html'
    }];

    $scope.currentTab = 'one.tpl.html';

    $scope.onClickTab = function(tab) {
      $scope.currentTab = tab.url;
    }

    $scope.isActiveTab = function(tabUrl) {
      return tabUrl == $scope.currentTab;
    }

    $scope.tab3 = 0;

    $scope.next = function() {
        $scope.tab3 = $scope.tab3 + 1;
    }
    $scope.prev = function() {
        $scope.tab3 = $scope.tab3 - 1;
    }


  }]);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yes this is what I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Rajan_Singh/6qm7jeo3/7/)

```
<ul>
  <li class="navBack" ng-click="navBack()"></li>
  <li ng-repeat="tab in tabs" ng-class="{active:isActiveTab(tab.url)}" ng-click="onClickTab(tab)">{{tab.title}}</li>
  <li class="navNext" ng-click="navNext()"></li>
</ul>

In Controller:

$scope.index = 0;
$scope.navBack = function(tab) {
  if($scope.index > 0)
  {
    $scope.index--;
  }
  $scope.currentTab = $scope.tabs[$scope.index].url;

}

$scope.navNext = function() {
  if( $scope.index < ($scope.tabs.length-1))
  {
    $scope.index++;
  }
  $scope.currentTab = $scope.tabs[$scope.index].url;

}
```